# How to get callback from the method RequestNavigate in Prism?

Tags: wpf, navigation, prism

I want to navigate using RegionManager

```
  regionManager.RequestNavigate("TabsView_region", "TabsView");
```

But it seems I've done something wrong, and nothing happens.
I'm sure that I registred TabsView for navigation. I've checked several times names of parameters. ViewModel of TabsView is connected with View through AutoWire. ViewModel implemets INavigationAware. I even created an empty project, where I simulated the same situation and in this case RequestNavigate works fine.

The question is if there is a way to get information, why navigation doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
regionManager.RequestNavigate("TabsView_region", "TabsView", result => { if (!result.Result) MessageBox.Show(result.Exception.ToString()); } );
```

?